# aggregating and counting in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, count

for the following df

```
group  participated
A           1
A           1
B           0
A           0
B           1
A           1
B           0
B           0
```

I want to count the total number of values in the participated column for each value in the group column (groupby-count) and then find a count of how many 1s there are in each group too

Something like

```
group tot_participated   1s
A         4              3
B         4              1
```

I know the first part is simple and can be done by a simple

```
grouped_df=df.groupby('group').count().reset_index()
```

unable to wrap my head around the second part. Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could follow the groupby with an aggregation as below:

```
grp_df = df.groupby('group', as_index=False).agg({'participated':['count','sum']})
grp_df.columns = ['group','tot_participated','1s']
grp_df.head()
```

The caveat to using .agg with multiple aggregation functions on the same column is that a multi-column index is created. This can be remedied by resetting the column names as in line 2.

Comment: thanks. will you mind telling how i could have counted number of 0s instead. I only ask coz i do not see the mention of the value 1 in line 1 and am unable to follow how the sum function counts 1s and ignores 0s

Comment: In line 1, we are performing 2 aggregations on the 'participated' column with each 'group', first we count how many values are present, second we sum all values within a group (which in this case is the same as counting how many 1's appear in each group). Does this help? I'll update the code for counting 0's shortly.